# Should interest on CFD positions be subtracted from UK capital gains?

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain, cfd

The question title says it all. If I open a CFD position and hold it for a while, I will be charged interest. Can that be subtracted from the net gain or loss of the trade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as per [CG56100](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg56100):

> Payments equivalent to interest that the investor makes or receives are not true interest. Similarly, no true dividends change hands. The amounts are instead entered into the capital gains computation. The investor should not show amounts received as investment income (interest or company dividends) on his or her return. And “interest” or “dividends” paid cannot be netted off against income.