# How to calculate proceeds when buying stock with borrowed money?

Tags: united-kingdom, interest, leverage

Suppose I borrow money and use it to buy stock, expecting the stock price to raise short-term.

HMRC [provides clear instructions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123707/should-interest-on-cfd-positions-be-subtracted-from-uk-capital-gains) on futures and contracts-for-difference (CFDs), but none on custom types of leverage, that is, when a trader borrows money from one place and buys the stock from another.

Can the charged interest be subtracted from the net gain (or loss) of the trade?

Note: the question is about the UK taxation system. In the US, the answer seems to be yes, as per [schwab.com](https://www.schwab.com/resource-center/insights/content/investment-expenses-whats-tax-deductible):

> In these cases, you may be able to deduct the interest on the margin loan. (This wouldn’t apply if you used the loan to buy tax-advantaged investments such as municipal bonds).

Comment: Note that in the U.S., investment interest is an itemized deduction. It can’t be used to adjust the gain or loss of the trade.

Comment: @prl How does that work? Isn't the overall result the same if you the deduct the interest from one category to another?

Comment: Paul, two main differences: you don’t get to deduct it in addition to the standard deduction; and the interest doesn’t reduce your “adjusted gross income” (AGI), which is used to determine all sorts of other income-based limits.